# Why is it that the MySQL index does not work in an AMI copy of the original machine?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-ami

Two indentical queries were carried in MySQL on the two machines for the same table, one is the original machine and the other is an newly booted copy from the AMI (which is made from that original machine). The query in the copy executes a lot slower than the one in the original machine (for e.g. 5min vs. 10secs). I checked the status of the table in each machine, and they turned out identical (which is natural). However, after I recreated the index in the copy, their performance became the same.

Why does this happen? Indexes are saved in the hard drive, and newly spawned AMI copies should have the same data, correct?

Comment: same data, perhaps not same index. Perhaps running `analyze table` of the clone would have triggered an index regen. Perhaps they are running on different instance types (conceivable, no?). Perhaps the AMI is left in a poor state such that the original machine rectified with subsequent use, it its world, yet clone picks up poor index state when spun up. Too many variables.

Answer (score 0):

A likely explanation is a cold cache and buffer pool... when the server starts up, it is [cold, not warm](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51981/11651) and isn't going to perform as well.

Rebuilding the index, most likely, only works because of its side effects -- it warms up the buffer pool and/or OS cache because it has to read the table in order to build the index.

Things to try, in order to prove or disprove this, after starting the server:

- run `CHECKSUM TABLE table_name` on each table
- make, and discard, a backup, with `mysqldump -u username -p --verbose --all-databases > /dev/null`.

If either of these serves the same purpose, then a lack of warm-up is your issue.

Or, skip right to what should be the solution, assuming InnoDB, and save/load the buffer pool at shutdown/startup:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-preload-buffer-pool.html

Comment: I tested it for a number of times so I assume a lack of warming up should not be a problem. I heard that when creating a machine from AMI, AWS does not copy all the data to your local machine unless trying to reach the data. But I still don't get how the index and AWS's manipulation came into play in this process of creation of a new machine.

Comment: Oh, of course... I overlooked the obvious.  For each EBS volume, warm up the *disk* using `sudo dd if=/dev/xvdX of=/dev/null bs=1M` where X is a, b, etc., for each volume you have attached.  That should indeed be the issue.  It isn't that the data isn't copied to the *machine*, it's that the data is loaded lazily+on-demand into EBS from the snapshot in S3 and this indeed will make a new machine crawl.  Again, rebuilding the index "fixes" this because it forces the volume to load from the snapshot.  It would eventually warm itself up but the `dd` on each disk should hasten that process.

Comment: Warming up EBS volumes is so second-nature to me that I honestly didn't think about it not already being done.  Let me know if this helps.  There's another approach that's more aggressive but this should do it.

Comment: More aggressive but still safe approach -- `$ sudo fio --filename=/dev/xvdX --rw=randread --bs=128k --iodepth=32 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --name=volume-initialize` again with `/dev/xvdX` being the volume's block device.